# React native: Open Facebook app instead of browser

Tags: react-native

I use linking API of react native to open facebook page and it works good but it opens on browser

```
  _visitFB = (url) => {
       Linking.openURL(url);
   }

onPress= {()=> this._visitFB('https://www.facebook.com/Arcolpeintures/')}
```

how can I open it on Facebook App ?

Comment: yes, you need to installed FB app first
and it work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 Linking.openURL("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/Arcolpeintures/");
```

or something like this:

```
Linking.openURL("fb://profile/426253597411506");
```

basically you need to find facebook url for the profile you are going to show

Comment: first suggest doesn't work :
no activity found to handle intent... i have to install facebook on my emolator ?

Comment: Opens Facebook app, but not the specific page in url